# How to automatically update a text file in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I have a file called ban.txt that has banned keywords in it. I have a webserver with the ban.txt located and I want my extension to keep in sync with the ban.txt on my server. How would I go about automatically updating that ban.txt file in the extension?

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).